# Как получить внешние координаты полигона?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Не могу разобраться, помогите пожалуйста. В общем суть: нужно нарисовать полигон и проверить вхождение координат в область. Вхождение проверяю (на PHP), все отлично, но когда рисую внешний полигон (через конструктор), то его в прямом смысле нет, т.е координаты получаю только от основного полигона...

Возвращение координат:
`polygon.geometry.getCoordinates(); // нет координат внешних полигонов`

зеленым обведены основные полигоны, красным - внешний полигон
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
polygon.geometry.getCoordinates()
```

Этот код возвращает все координаты которые есть у полигона. Ищите ошибку в своем коде. Скорее всего вы не учитываете, что getCoordinates возвращает массив массивов. В этом примере видно как это выглядит https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon

Кстати вхождение очень просто проверяется с помощью метода polygon.geometry.contains(coords) https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geometry.Polygon-docpage/

Comment: "Скорее всего вы не учитываете, что getCoordinates возвращает массив массивов."

Спасибо! Так и есть я этого не учитывал...

"Кстати вхождение очень просто проверяется с помощью метода" да, про constains() я знаю, мне кроме клиентской проверки нужна еще проверка на сервере, т.к все это будет хранится в БД